# Comparing AX2009 user groups permissions

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any way I can quickly compare 2 user groups and find out the missing permissions in MS Dynamics AX 2009.

Right now I am accessing Administration > Setup > User Groups
. Then I have to select each group and make a snapshot of it or export it and the compare the permissions, which can be a time consuming task.

When you have to analyze the already existing groups, a faster solution is needed.

Comment: Yes, you could write some code to do it.

Comment: Moreover, you should write a code. ax2009 have not standard functionality to compare user group permissions.

Comment: This is an option for you, but takes a little advanced know-how to follow plus you'd have to modify it for AX09, which is dramatically different. But some concepts could transfer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dynamicsaxscm/2011/08/26/visualizing-security-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/